# My LG is indicating low storage space

Tags: internal-storage

My LG is indicating low storage space. I cannot install new applications. I still have more than 7G free space. Please what can i do?

Comment: Here is the salvation: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info. Also, give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage). You may have to delete an app or an app's data  to get some space for the said apps' installation.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good tactic to reboot the phone clear up useless apps and move your pics or whatever to another place(may be sd card?).you should check the storage options in settings and that will tell you whats causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is becasue of cache files go in settings>storages>cache data and clear them....and some of google apps like gmail and google now saves alot of data on your device be sure to clear that and go in storage and apps section and it ll show you the list of apps sorted on basis of their size(large to small)....clear their data...

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned 7G free space,but in sd card or in internal memory?

all apps and app data may be stored in your internal storage.
Move your data to SD card and try installing new apps.
hope this will be helpful.